# Javascript JQuery concatenatation of variable(form.inputtag.value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, concatenation

I have the below script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function get(row){
        alert(row);
        $.post ('getpeopleinjobs.php',{ 
        postvarposition: form.position1.value,
        postvarjob: form.job1.value, 
        postvarperson: form.person1.value, 
        postrow: row}, 
            function(output){
                $('#training'+row).html(output).show();
                    });
                }
</script>
```

This works 100%. However I want the '1' or number appended to position, job and person to be the variable 'row'. something like the below(which does not work)

postvarposition: form.position+row.value

i did try form[position+row].value as per advice from another post but this does not work.

The alert(row) returns 1 if the onchange="get(1)" and 2 if the onchange="get(2)" etc so this is working.

How can I concatenate the row variable onto the positon, job, and person statement so that as row increases in value I'll get
form.position1.value
form.position2.value
form.position3.value etc etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: postvarposition: row+'_'+form.position1.value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the form values by string

```
form["position" + row].value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery selector to get value of inputs.

```
$('#prefix' + row).val()
```

### HTML

```
<input id="job1" name="job1" type="text"/>
<input id="person1" name="person1" type="text"/>
<input id="position1" name="position1" type="text"/>

<input id="job2" name="job2" type="text"/>
<input id="person2" name="person2" type="text"/>
<input id="position2" name="position2" type="text"/>

<input id="job3" name="job3" type="text"/>
<input id="person3" name="person3" type="text"/>
<input id="position3" name="position3" type="text"/>
```

### jquery

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){ //each row
    var postvars = {
        job : $('input#job'+i).val();
        person : $('input#person'+i).val();
        position : $('input#position'+i).val();
    }
//
    $.post('url/to/ajax', postvars, function(output){
        $('#training'+i).html(output).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: That @ai.farfa, I will definately try this approach too so I can learn.